# Check during installation of .msi package if IIS features are enabled in system

Tags: iis, wix, windows-installer

Is there any way to check that features of IIS are enabled in the system during the installation process?

For instance, for checking version of .NET framework and applying some condition we can use this example taken from:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20"/>

<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 2.0. Please 
    install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK20]]>
</Condition>
```

But is there any possibility to check for features of IIS being enabled?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's been ages since I did anything with IIS, but maybe check this documentation?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components

Answer (score 0):

This registry key lists installed components

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components
```

If a component hasn't been installed, it won't show up in that list

So if you wanted to block installation if the HTTP Redirect feature wasn't enabled, you can do this:

```
    <Property Id="REDIRECT">
        <RegistrySearch Id="redirects" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components" Name="HttpRedirect" Type="raw" />
    </Property>
    <Condition Message='HTTP Redirection is not configured in IIS. Please install HTTP Redirection in IIS first, and then $(var.ProductName).'><![CDATA[Installed OR REDIRECT]]></Condition>
```

A more customer friendly approach however, might be to enable the features that you need as part of your install.
You can do that in your installer by calling the DISM utility:

```
    <CustomAction Id='AddIISComponent' Property='IISComponent' Value='"[System64Folder]dism.exe" /norestart /quiet /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-HttpRedirect /all' Execute='immediate'/>
    <CustomAction Id="IISComponent" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="AddIISComponent" After="CostFinalize" />
        <Custom Action="IISComponent" After="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[(NOT Installed)]]></Custom> 
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Note the /featurename:IIS-HttpRedirect in the command line

You can get a list of the possible feature names by running

```
dism /online /Get-Features
```